The video tag does not autoplay when the source is mapped to a variable in a Blazor Server app .net 6
While using the source as a variable, the video does not autoplay. However, it works properly if the source is used directly.
Project blazor server app .net 6
<video id="videoPlayer" width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay muted playsinline loop>
    <source src="@src" type="video/mp4">
</video>

@code {
    string src = "Videos/RPReplay_Final1732704033.mp4";
}

It is working properly while play the video using Js. The video tag should autoplay properly whether the source is set using a variable or a direct path.
